# R: Index corresponding to maximum value in each row

Tags: r, loops, max

I have a 744 x 3 matrix (named sharpe_a) that I am looping over to create a dataframe composed of the index value corresponding to the maximum for each row (named last_bestIndex_colnum)

The issue is that it is treating two values with identical **absolute** value but **opposite signs** as equivalents.

```
        sr_sig_fx sr_comm_i sr_comm_ii
[1,]        NA        NA         NA
[2,]        NA    0.2632    -0.5714
[3,]   -0.3684    0.3684    -0.2222
[4,]    0.3846   -0.3846    -0.5000
```

so when using grep to identify the column containing the maximum value for row 3, for example, I get the following

```
> grep(max(x[3,]),x[3,])
[1] 1 2
```

so instead of just returning 2, it thinks -0.3684 and 0.3684 are the same value so are returning 1 and 2. However, I test x[3,1] > x[3,2] and it returns "FALSE", then x[3,1] < x[3,2] and it returns "TRUE" so I am assuming that grep and max are doing something to x but I am not sure what or why.

```
structure(c(NA, NA, -0.3684, 0.3846, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7895, 0.9412, 
0.55, 0.25, NA, 0.2632, 0.3684, -0.3846, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7895, 
-0.9412, -0.55, -0.25, NA, -0.5714, -0.2222, -0.5, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7895, -1, -0.8235, -1), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("sr_sig_fx", "sr_comm_i", "sr_comm_ii")))
```

Comment: Did you try `max.col(replace(x, is.na(x), -Inf))` ?

Comment: That seems like a good solution -- however that returns, for example, "3" for rows where all 3 columns are NA. I also need there to be NA when there are ties for the maximum value in the row. Is there a way to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use grep like that, it correctly identifies 0.3684 as the maximum, then returns all columns that contain 0.3684, irregardless of the negative; grep is meant for strings. Try:

`which(x[1,] == max(x[1,][!is.na(x[1,]))`

Edit:
Just noticed in the comments that you want to return `NA` when there is a tie between two values. This could be accomplished like so:

```
result <- which(x[1,] == max(x[1,][!is.na(x[1,]))
result <- ifelse(length(result) > 1, NA, result)
```

Comment: when I run your solution I get: Error in last_bestIndex_colnum[i, j] <- ifelse(length(last_bestIndex_colnum) >  : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In max(x[1, ][!is.na(x[1, ])]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: I rearranged the terms in your suggestion and believe I figured out what I needed: ifelse(length(which(sharpe_a[[j]][i,] == max ( sharpe_a[[j]][i,],na.rm=T))) > 1,
                                         NA,which(sharpe_a[[j]][i,] == max ( sharpe_a[[j]][i,],na.rm=T)) )

Comment: Good stuff, I'm guessing that cases where all the values in a row are NA might have tripped up my suggestion. Glad you figured out a way to make it work.

PS.  I highly recommend reading this (free) book if you want to further develop your R skills. You'd learn a lot of techniques that will help you deal with the kind of stuff you've outlined in this post.

https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html